# Ubuntu unresponsive (but running) after opening an app in favourites

Tags: usb, 22.04

I have been using an old computer which I have determined the SATA cable/port of that computer is broken and unusable, as any hard drive I have tried to put in there has gotten corrupted beyond repair (within a reasonable time frame). For this reason, I have been booting the computer of of USB.

I used a live USB flash drive to install Ubuntu to another USB flash drive, meaning this is not a live environment. Any time I click an app in my favorites, it starts to drag around for quite a while, leaving me unable to control the computer as it does not let me press any buttons. Trying to use the Tab and arrow keys to navigate does nothing, and Ctrl + Shift + T does not open the terminal. After several minutes, I am able to stop it from dragging around and am able to control the computer again, but the process repeats everything I open another app (from the favorites menu).

I have never had this problem on physical hardware or in a VM. I'm a noob at Linux in general.

Comment: sounds like a very slow USB, and it takes a while to read the app's code into memory, can you confirm this happens when you load an app from anywhere, not just the favorites menu? Also, computer specs please? Is it swapping heavily because it lacks RAM? With such slow storage, that would make things even worse...

Comment: also, "old computer" will imply probably USB-2 or even USB-1 speeds, so even if you have a new and fast USB drive, the computer may be incapable of using it at fast speeds.

Comment: @Esther. I am not sure of the computer USB capabilities, however it does take quite a while for applications to load. It has 8gb of RAM. The USB loads fine, I've been using it for my general ubuntu-y stuff for a while and it's ok for what I do with it. The dragging around problem is not a result of the speed, as other people have also reported this happening, nor is it a result of the USB. It works just fine after updating the drivers and the system as a whole using sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade -y.